# Displaying a div automatically on page load

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am trying to display a css modal box, which should pop up for a user if he has mail in his inbox, on page load. I got it working so far for a link `<a href="#" id="mail_modal"></a>`, but I'm not sure how to make it appear automatically upon page load. This is my code:

```
<?php
if ($items > 0)
    {
        echo '<strong><font color="yellow">You have new unread mail</font></strong>';
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_modal').click(function(e) { 
            $('#modal').reveal({ 
                animation: 'fadeAndPop', 
                animationspeed: 400,   
                closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
                dismissmodalclass: 'close'
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="modal">

        <div id="mail-form">

            <h1>New Mail</h1>

            <fieldset>

                <form name="loginform" action="<?php echo url('/Mail');?>">

                    <p>You have new unread mail in your inbox. Press 'Mail' button to access your inbox.</p>

                    <input type="hidden" name="redir" value="<?php echo url('/Mail'); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mail" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Mail" />

                </form>

            </fieldset>

        </div> <!-- end login-form -->

    </div>

    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<i>You have no new mail</i>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button_modal').click(function(e) { 
    $('#modal').reveal({ 
      animation: 'fadeAndPop', 
      animationspeed: 400,   
      closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
      dismissmodalclass: 'close'
    });
    return false;
  });

  // and here we show popup automatically, if a user has new letters.
  <?php if ($items > 0) echo "$('#button_modal').trigger('click');"; ?>

});
</script>
```

Comment: It works, thank you, but there's an issue, because you can't exit it. I think the entire page basically becomes a `/Mail` link. I'm thinking that I could reset the `$items` to `0`, but how can I do that on submit?

Comment: Usually there must be a method, closing a popup, like: ('#modal').reveal('close');. Can you check the documentation?

Comment: It doesn't appear at all sadly. Apparently, this closes the popup: `closeonbackgroundclick: true`. The modal also had a span which closed it but I did not want it in there. Your first code however worked, I'm just wondering whether it would be good practice to set `$items = 0` upon submit?

Comment: Do you mean, that "closeonbackgroundclick: true" doesn't work? And I updated the line, where modal is called. $('#button_modal').trigger('click'); Make sure this line is visible on the page.

Comment: It doesn't. For some reason the background acts as a link to `/Mail`.

Comment: Can you send a link to your page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24853/discussion-between-webars-and-zzwyb89)

Comment: I'm afraid, it's on a localhost server, don't want to mess my site up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(/* check if has mail */ === true) {
        $('#modal').reveal({ 
            animation: 'fadeAndPop', 
            animationspeed: 400,   
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, 
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Will this automatically appear on page load?

Comment: When the document is ready (meaning the page has loaded) the code within the block is executed meaning it will reveal the modal.

Comment: Could also wrap in a PHP `if` statement rather than including the `if` statement in JS.

Comment: In your case just add the `$('#modal').reveal();` block to `$(document).ready();`